# TThreadList access violation on locklist

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

```
var   all: TThreadList = nil;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var  list:tlist;
begin
  try
  list := all.LockList;
  try
    list.Add(0);
  finally
    all.UnlockList;
  end;
  except

  end;
end;
```

telnet 127.0.0.1 1234

why it's getting access violation ?

Answer (score 8):

I expect you simply forgot to create the `TThreadList`. You need

```
all := TThreadList.Create;
```

somewhere. For example, in the `initialization` section of that unit.

Comment: Whenever you get an access violation on a method call, check whether or not the instance variable is valid. In the debugger, you will see that `all` evaluates to `nil`. That's your tell tale sign.

Comment: Local POD-type variables, like raw pointers, are not initialized to zero/nil. So no, it is not guaranteed that the debugger would show `nil` for the `all` variable.

Comment: @Remy, in this case yes, since OP has it initialized to `nil`.

Comment: @TLama: sorry, my bad.  I read the code wrong, I didn't notice `all` was a global variable.

Comment: @waza123 Is this the answer to your question?